# Remove Eclipse specific preference pages from my application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, preferences

I have an RCP application with some custom preference pages, but among them I can see other Eclipse specific preference pages. How can I remove them, I searched the whole project but did not find any reference to them. Any idea where are they added?

[image]

Comment: They're added through the Preference Pages extension point,  http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_preferencePages.html?cp=2_1_1_189 in plug-ins that you're including in your product/launch.

Comment: the only pages that are added through PreferencePages extension in plugin.xml are my own custom preference pages. No idea still where those yellow highlighted pages are defined..